# Jenkins build failing with gem:command not found

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to setup jenkins but it keeps failing on the `execute shell` part.

I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/hudson1424221209017954242.sh: line 8: gem: command not found
/tmp/hudson1424221209017954242.sh: line 9: bundle: command not found
/tmp/hudson1424221209017954242.sh: line 12: bundle: command not found
```

I've set up rvm globally (located at /usr/local/rvm/). The user `jenkins`, where jenkins is stored, can run bundle via ssh.

Here's the `execute shell` commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /var/lib/jenkins/.bashrc
# enter application root
cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/topboard/workspace
# install missing gems
rvm use 2.1.2@gemset --create
# set env vars
gem install bundler
bundle install
export RAILS_ENV=test
# invoke rake
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate ci:setup:rspec
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be an RVM installation issue - how did you install RVM? Is it included in the PATH? (it should be included in ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc to make it available in both interactive and non interactive shell sessions)

Comment: I installed it globally in the VPS instance. In that case, do I need to reinstall it in the user itself? or can I direct it via .bash_profile?

Comment: if you install RVM globally (in multi user mode as it is referred in RVM docs) you have to add every user you want to use RVM with to the RVM group. RVM install should create an OS group called "rvm" - you should add the users to this.

Comment: You can find more info about the multi user mode on the official RVM install docs page: [https://rvm.io/rvm/install](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) - search for "multi-user" - especially the "Load RVM into your shell sessions as a function" section